# NullPointerException when run a test using PageObjects pattern

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng, pageobjects

I have tried to find the answer to this but none of those helped me. I'm sure I'm missing one detail, but I can't figure out what exactly.

I get `NullPointerException` when run a test case. I think it happens when I try to pass driver to my page object (`WikiMain`), which is inherited from `WebPage` (superclass), because when I debugged, I noticed driver = null. Should I pass the driver to `WebPage`, because other pages are inherited from it?
P.S. Sorry I'm kind of new to this and it's my first questions on this website.

Here is my Test Case class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class TestCase{

    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp(){
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown(){
        driver.quit();
    }

    public WebPage getWikiMain(){
        driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org/");
        return new WikiMain(driver);
    }
}
```

Here is my WebPage class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class WebPage{

    private WebDriver driver;

    public WebPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        initWebElements();
    }

    public void initWebElements(){
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

Here is WikiMain class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class WikiMain extends WebPage{

    private WebDriver driver;

    public WikiMain(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }


    public WebPage getWikiEn(){
        String linkToWikiEn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class= 'central-featured-lang lang1']/a")).getAttribute("href");
        driver.get(linkToWikiEn);
        return new WikiMainEn(driver);
    }
}
```

And WikiMainEn class:

```
package com.company.pages;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;


public class WikiMainEn extends WebPage{

    private WebDriver driver;

    public WikiMainEn(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='mp-topbanner']/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]")
    private WebElement title;

    public WebElement getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String getTitleText(){
        return getTitle().getText();
    }
}
```

And actual Test:

```
import com.company.pages.*;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class TestWikiMain extends TestCase{

    @Test
    public void verifyEnWiki() {

        WikiMain wikiMain = (WikiMain) getWikiMain();
        WikiMainEn wikiMainEn = (WikiMainEn) wikiMain.getWikiEn();
        Assert.assertTrue(wikiMainEn.getTitleText().contains("Welcome to"));
    }
```

Comment: In your `testCase()` class, should the annotation be `@BeforeClass` instead of `@BeforeTest` (as per the [TestNG homepage example](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) SimpleTest.java)?

Comment: @Bobulous ,
Yes it could be BeforeClass or BeforeMethod, I just used BeforeTest because I was practicing with DataProvider and I just didn't replace it. But it doesn't make a difference here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class TestCase{
   public WebDriver driver;

   @BeforeTest
   public void setUp(){
       driver = new ChromeDriver();
   }
```

Here you have declared a driver and initialized.

```
public class WikiMain extends WebPage{

private WebDriver driver;

public WikiMain(WebDriver driver){
    super(driver);
}
```

Another driver without any initialaztion. So when you ran here

```
 WikiMainEn wikiMainEn = (WikiMainEn) wikiMain.getWikiEn();
```

You were using a uninitialized driver. Because you've never initilize the subclass's(WikiMain) driver. You just initilized WebPage.class 's driver.

In my opinion you can set the WebPage's driver protected and remove the subclass one.

```
 protected WebDriver driver;
```

And remove

```
public class WikiMain extends WebPage{

 private WebDriver driver; //remove it
```

Comment: Yes it worked, Oh so basically it didn't matter when I passed the driver to WikiMain because another., uninitialized driver was declared there and was null by default. Thanks a lot!